# Rails 4 belongs_to store ids in array column

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, belongs-to

I have a **Topic** model that belongs to **Category** and **Level**.

Knowing that each Topic belongs to maximum 5-6 Level and 2-3 categories, could the category ids and the level ids of each topic be stored in 2 columns using array:true of Postgresql or is it bad practice to do so?

Answer (score 1):

Would a `has_and_belongs_to_many` relationship work for you?

```
class Topic
  has_and_belongs_to_many :levels
  has_and_belongs_to_many :categories
end

class Category
  has_and_belongs_to_many :topics
end

class Level
  has_and_belongs_to_many :topics
end

create_table :categories_topics do |t|
  t.integer :topic_id
  t.integer :category_id
end

create_table :levels_topics do |t|
  t.integer :level_id
  t.integer :topic_id
end
```

This would make the structure look like:

```
|--------|      |--------------|
| Topics | ---> | LevelsTopics |
|--------|      |--------------|
                    ^
|--------|          |
| Levels | ---------|
|--------|


|--------|      |-------------------|
| Topics | ---> | CategoriesTopics  |
|--------|      |-------------------|
                        ^
|------------|          |
| Categories | ---------|
|------------|
```

This way there is a single row for each Topic, a single row for each Level and a single row for each Category. The relationship logic will be contained in a new table so everything stays DRY.

Read more about [has_and_belongs_to_many](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods/has_and_belongs_to_many)

Comment: That sounds good but the problem is when you request the topics in an index action, how do fetch the associated levels and categories without doing N+1 queries? Do you have to issue 3 different queries (Category.all, Topic.all and Level.all)?

Comment: You can use `references` and `includes`: It might look something like `Topic.where(id: 1).includes(:levels).references(:levels)`

Comment: To fetch a single Topic that's the way, but it is not clear not how to proceed with the Topic index method (Topic.all) to display also the categories and levels...

Comment: You would just remove the `where` clause: `Topic.includes(:levels).references(:levels)`

Comment: You actually don't need the `references` in those queries. `Topic.includes` will load everything it needs using either the `preload` or `eager_load` strategy. http://blog.arkency.com/2013/12/rails4-preloading/